# Is it better to transfer records between databases via mysql or rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

We're running a production server with various lessons on it, and are in the process of creating a demo server with limited access. Each lesson takes around an hour to create in our CMS, and I'm trying to create a way to transfer lessons created there into our other environment through a button click. My end aim is to have records with identical primary ID's in both databases

My first question is, is tackling this through Ruby rather than SQL the right way to go? I can setup a service that submits a request to the demo server, with the correct params, but this will create new records with ID's that don't match up. Is it preferable for me to write a script that would take the object attributes as arguments, and create the records directly via mysql? And if so what's the best approach for that? Invoking a rake task?

Apologies for the open ended question but I'm not sure where else I can ask, and have found no resources on copying records between databases in a rails app (just duplicating objects within the same environment)

Comment: Is dumping the db and restoring it on another server not an option?

Comment: Why not dump your database and restore on the demo env?

Comment: @Eyeslandic: haha, great minds think alike :)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned - the demo DB will have records that are individual to it - we're tracking user activity there and can't just nuke the whole thing unfortunately

Comment: However tables that require duplicated records will only contain those duplicated records so clashing ID's won't be a problem

Comment: So? Dump/restore only those tables then.

Comment: We wouldn't be transferring the whole table over though, we only want select records with their associated objects to the demo environment, and I'm trying to figure out a way to allow users to do this without involving the developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the demo server is not read-only - in generic situation you easily can face situation where ids that you're going to inject - are already taken.

As for process itself - I'd introduce a serialisation format for lessons (json dump or any other), so that they can be imported and exported in a single transaction.
Then you can either allow users manually transfer these dumps or add an api that will do that (in this case you're adding a knowledge about demo server to the production one, which is not always desirable architecture-wise)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I was hoping to keep it strictly rails based but it looks like collecting all the information in a json and then importing directly through SQL is the best way to go. Thanks again!